# How to make UITextView multiple line alignment change all at once?

Tags: ios, alignment, uitextview

Hi I have 3 buttons on the UI, which changes the UITextView alignment for "Left", "Center", "Right".

The logic is when the corresponding button is pressed, then in code set "UITextView.textAlignment = .left/.right/.center".

However, I found that after the alignment is set, if the text has multiple lines, the logic only changes the text alignment one line at a time.

I tried "UITextView.updateSubViewLayouts()" also "UITextView.setTextNeedsUpdate()", but none of them works.

How can I change the entire paragraph's alignment all together?

Thanks!

Comment: I just tested and there is nothing wrong with changing the text alignment. Please post your code and if possible, screenshots of what the app is showing

Answer (score 0):

I add 3 buttons to change textalignment,and it changes for all text

```
switch sender.tag {
    case 1:
        text.textAlignment = .left
    case 2:
        text.textAlignment = .center
    case 3:
        text.textAlignment = .right
    default:
        break
    }
```

[left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFLna.png)

[center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad0GX.png)

right looks same as center